# Installing Fabric.js on Rails with bower

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, fabricjs

I installed Fabric.js with bower in my Rails projects, but have trobles with assets pipeline. With `//= require fabric` I'm getting an error `couldn't find file 'fabric'`.

By the way, in `bower.json` file it has a title `fabric.js`, but `//= require fabric.js` returns the same error. **What is the proper name of Fabric.js for assets-pipeline then?**

All other bower components are integrating perfectly.

Comment: There is no proper name for this lib, you should declare a path to main `fabric.js`. `//= require path/to/main_file/fabric` without an extension.

Comment: But, for example, for EaselJS I just write `//= require EaselJS` and everything works fine.

Comment: It's depends on the `bower.json` main file and the Rails assets paths configuration.IMO

Comment: I tried to change path to the main path in `bower.json` -- no results. I know, that `//= require fabric.js/dist/fabric.js` works, but just don't like it aesthetically.

Comment: you can omit the extension just `//= require fabric.js/dist/fabric` also works, _I tried to change path to the main path in bower.json_ this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no proper name for this lib, you should declare a path to main fabric.js, like so

```
//= fabric.js/dist/fabric
```